# Getting null, $sum aggregate - Mongo

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting [] when trying to sum up budget values in the campaign collection by vendorID?

Heres my *documen*t in the DB - `Campaign Collection`

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5acf6ca923cdca5be18518cf"),
"vendorID" : ObjectId("5acf11eaeab7b52d8403ac17"),
"bookingID" : ObjectId("5acf6c9123cdca5be18518ce"),
"listingID" : ObjectId("5acf6c4d23cdca5be18518cd"),
"budget" : 200000,
"date" : "Thu Apr 12 2018 17:26:49 GMT+0300 (EAT)",
"__v" : 0
}
```

Here's the *router* block I'm using

```
router.get('/campaign_sum/:vendorID', (req, res, next) => {
Campaign.aggregate([
    { $match : { "vendorID" : req.params.vendorID } },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: { $sum: "$budget" }
        }
    }
], (err, value) => {
    res.json(value);
});
});
```

Comment: Try to convert your id in ObjectId before passing it to the aggregate function

Comment: How should I go about this?

Comment: like this: `_id: new ObjectId(id)`

Comment: Im getting this ObjectId is not defined

Comment: before adding above code, u need to import module: `ObjectId = require('mongodb');`

Comment: adding this worked: var newVendor = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.vendorID);
just above to convert the ObjectID
thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First require mongoose like this:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Then use:

```
{ $match : { "vendorID" :  Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.vendorID)} }
```

instead of:

```
{ $match : { "vendorID" : req.params.vendorID } }
```